# MaskedInput text is not correctly displayed when it received through the props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend, text-mask

I have a a Material UI `OutlinedInput` on top of which I'm using `MaskedInput`from `react-text-mask`, when I originally put text into it and element is not in focus, the inputted text displays correctly, however when I close down the Dialog window with this component and reopen there's some strange behavior with text overplapping over placeholder text.

That looks like this:

[image: overlapped image]

When I originally input text:

[image: originally inputted text image]

Here's my code for this component:

```
const SERIES_MASK = [/\d/, /\d/, " ", /\d/, /\d/];

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  inputLabel: {
   margin: "-8px 0 0 14px",
  },
});

const SeriesMask: FC<{}> = (props) => <MaskedInput {...props} mask={SERIES_MASK} />;

export const DocumentSeriesField: FC<{
   name: string;
   value: string;
   label: string;
   error?: string;
   onChange: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
   onBlur: (e: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
   }> = ({ name, value, label, error, onChange, onBlur }) => {
      const classes = useStyles();
      const id = useMemo(() => randomId("series"), []);

      return (
       <FormControl>
         <InputLabel htmlFor={id} error={Boolean(error)} classes={{ root: classes.inputLabel }}>
          {label}
         </InputLabel>
         <OutlinedInput id={id} name={name} value={value} label={label} inputComponent={SeriesMask} error={Boolean(error)} onChange={onChange} onBlur={onBlur} />
         <FormHelperText error={Boolean(error)}>{error}</FormHelperText>
       </FormControl>
    );
};
```

Could you please tell me what could be a possible issue here and how could it be fixed?

Comment: Does `useStyles` work correctly? It looks like `InputLabel` doesn't get any styling after the dialog is reopened

Comment: @UjinT34

Yes, i think it does. I just removed the useStyles object from this snippet but it looks like this:

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  inputLabel: {
    margin: "-8px 0 0 14px",
  },
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing reference of the Outlined Input in MaskedInput

Try to pass `inputRef` to `MaskedInput`, the label should be able to find the field is filled and go back up to the border instead of overlaying.

**SeriesMask**

```js
interface SeriesMaskRefProps {
  inputRef: (ref: HTMLInputElement | null) => void;
} 

const SeriesMask: FC<{}> = (props: InputBaseComponentProps) => (
  <MaskedInput
    {...props}
    ref={(ref: any) => {
      (props as SeriesMaskRefProps).inputRef(ref ? ref.inputElement : null);
    }} // pass the ref to allow input label to connect with maaksed input
    mask={SERIES_MASK}
  />
);
```

Comment: Thank you! I applied those changes all over my project and it worked.